# Using Neural Network for Price Forecasting is right or not?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am doing a project on price forecasting using neural Network. Conventionally neural network is used for classification. In our context we are using `neuralnet` package in R language for price forecast by training the dataset with already existing information of a product. It predicts future demand for a product by using the input like advertising spending, promotional expenses, quarterly sales etc.
Here is the sample train set data

```
Advertising spending   promotional expenses   quarterly sales   Future Price 
            4949.014                7409.23          43500.21          16793
             5369.13                7903.12          20209.11          22455
             6149.23                9289.34          47640.15          25900
             6655.24                9914.01          34563.21          25591
```

The following are the neural network parameters,

```
net = neuralnet(predict.furure~advertising.spending + promotional.expenses + quarterly.sales, 
                data=traindata.norm, hidden=3, threshold = 0.1, startweights=NULL, 
                rep=100, learningrate=0.02, algorithm="backprop", lifesign="full", 
                err.fct="sse", act.fct="logistic")
```

In very simple sense, current month price (June 2015) for a product A it is X. So it I’ll predict Future Price of a product A in OCT 2015, Dec 2015 etc. 
For a test set, following result can be arrived after training.

```
Actual (Of benchmark or dataset)    prediction by neural net
                           81030                 86901.57818   
                           86686                 80938.02441 
                           97088                 87538.63362  
                          108739                107872.53769
```

I felt that the output arrived by using `neuralnet` package may not be correct. So I have tried to use `forecast`, `caret` packages.
Here is the code:

```
library(forecast)                                      
datas = ts(dataset)                                          
ts1test = window(datas,start=10,end=20) 
est1 = ets(ts1train[1:10])             
est2 = ets(ts1test[10:20],model=est1)             
onefit = fitted(est2)    
fore = forecast(onefit)

fore
```

Kindly request you to suggest me the best method in above two packages or any other better approach and also suggest whether neural network can be used for price forecasting.

Answer (score 1):

First of all BPN should not be used with 3 hidden layers. This is because back propagating the weights by three layers isn't really helpful and that is why they invented the field of Deep Learning. So I would suggest you reduce the hidden layer to one first and try it with.

I would suggest you start of using something simple like Linear Regression since it is used for price prediction and all. And yes ANN's can be used for price prediction.

Could you explain why you felt the output from the first package may not be correct? . And maybe I can suggest some extra changes